# On XP, how do I get the tooltip to appear above a transclucent form?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, tooltip, opacity

I have an form with an `Opacity` less then 1.0.  I have a tooltip associated with a label on the form.  When I hover the mouse over the label, the tooltip shows up *under* the form instead of *over* the form.  If I leave the Opacity at its default value of 1.0, the tooltip correctly appears over the form.  However, my form is obviously no longer translucent. ;-)

I have tried manually adjusting the position of the ToolTip with `SetWindowPos()` and creating a ToolTip "by hand" using `CreateWindowEx()`, but the problem remains.  This makes me suspect its a Win32 API problem, not a problem with the Windows Forms implementation that runs on top of Win32.

Why does the tooltip appear under the form, and, more importantly, how can I get it to appear over the form where it should?

**Edit**: this appears to be an XP-only problem.  Vista and Windows 7 work correctly.  I'd still like to find a workaround to get the tooltip to appear above the form on XP.

Here is a minimal program to demonstrate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private ToolTip toolTip1;
    private Label label1;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
        label1 = new Label();
        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 127);
        label1.Text = "Hover over me";
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(label1, "This is a moderately long string, "
               + "designed to be very long so that it will also be quite long.");
        ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 268);
        Controls.Add(label1);
        Opacity = 0.8;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing a minimal example, even though I couldn't reproduce it myself.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you set the Opacity, the native window gets the WS_EX_LAYERED style and that is why the bug only appears when the opacity is < 1.0 (Layered windows are a little special, they are composited onto the screen as late as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me!

[image]

Using .NET 3.5 on Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks for trying!  Maybe it's an XP bug that Microsoft fixed in later versions of Windows.

Comment: It works fine on the Windows 7 machine I have access to, as well.  Must be an XP problem.

Answer (score 3):

XP is known for having z-order [tooltip](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912650) [bugs](http://windowssucks.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/peekaboo-tooltip/). When you used SetWindowPos() on the tooltip, did you mark it as always on top with HWND_TOPMOST?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting HWND_TOPMOST, but it didn't help.  The links you gave me have given me some other ideas to try.  I'll let you know if any of them pan out.